# sed removing text after character not always working

Tags: bash, sed

So I have been using the following general syntax to be able to remove text on a line within a configuration file after the '=' sign:

```
sed -i 's|\(.*\txt_to_remove=\).*|\1|g' file.txt
```

Let's say I have a text file:

```
$ cat tmp.txt
datee='10'
alter='purple'
hr='green'
new_val='100'
```

and if I consecutively use the command I provided above to try and delete everything after '=':

```
sed -i 's|\(.*\datee=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
sed -i 's|\(.*\alter=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
sed -i 's|\(.*\hr=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
sed -i 's|\(.*\new_val=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
```

The results will be:

```
$ cat tmp.txt
datee=
alter='purple'
hr=
new_val='100'
```

The question is, why did the commands not work for the 'alter' or 'new_val', and what can be done to make sure that it always works for each individual instance of using the command?

Comment: Why do you have `\alter` instead of just `alter`?

Comment: you don't want to escape (ie, preceed with a '\') normal letters; `\a` and `\n` have special meaning to `sed` so you get no matches on the strings starting with `a` and `n`; the other 2 `sed` calls work because `\d` and `\h` don't have a special meaning to `sed`; try removing the '\' from `\d`, `\a`, `\h` and `\n`; note: `\d` does have a special meaning but only when the `d` is followed by 3 numbers; see [GNU sed - escape sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a backslash before the keyword that you want to replace. Backslash is the escape prefix, and `\a` and `\n` are escape sequences, so they don't match what's in the file.

Get rid of these backslashes.

```
sed -i 's|\(.*datee=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
sed -i 's|\(.*alter=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
sed -i 's|\(.*hr=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
sed -i 's|\(.*new_val=\).*|\1|g' tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Do them all at once with:

```
sed -i 's/^\(\(datee\|alter\|hr\|new_val\)=\).*/\1/g' tmp.txt
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but there might be a different number of things to alter depending on the situation

Answer (score 1):

try this sed expression `sed 's/=.*//'`
I tried and got the desired results

```
cat tmp.txt | sed 's/=.*//'
datee
alter
hr
new_val
```

Comment: She doesn't want to remove all values, just the 4 settings listed in the sed commands.

Comment: This is good if I was looking to do everything, but I invoke the command whenever for specific text instances. This is still a handy command.